# How to use Diffie Hellman algorithm at the browser?

Tags: cryptography, diffie-hellman, node.js

I want to use nodeJS as a server side language. NodeJS have crypto module where DiffieHellman is a class. So, I can use this method to generate key and compute key.

But, client also need to create another instance of diffiehellman class. But how to do that? Can I use crypto module on client side? If yes then how, any solution?
Here are my client side code...

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Generate server's keys...
const server = crypto.createDiffieHellman(139);
const serverKey = server.generateKeys();
//send p=prime and g=generator to the client
```

Comment: A very similar question was asked just yesterday: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/237260/diffie-hellman-implementation-nodejs

Comment: Yes, yesterday I asked this question. But, in my past question I have confusion whether  p and g is publicly available or not. But, today I asked how to use Diffie-hellman class on client side?

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you are this confused by DH, you probably shouldn't be using it.

Comment: `const client = crypto.createDiffieHellman(server.getPrime(), server.getGenerator());` how to execute this on client? (-_-)

Comment: Yes, i cam understand that p and g need to pass. But, look here are a method `createDiffieHellman`. I want to say how i use this method on client side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you're planning to achieve here, but it appears there's such port for browser:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-browserify.
`createDiffieHellman` is on the list of already ported modules. Especially take a look at the example: https://github.com/crypto-browserify/crypto-browserify/tree/master/example. Instead of `createHash` I believe you could try invoking `createDiffieHellman`.

Comment: It is the right answer. But, i facing  an error. How to use commonJS (require) syntax on ES6 environment?

Comment: I believe the `require` function is in bundle.js. In the example, bundle.js is loaded as a standard client-side js script: `<script src=bundle.js></script>`

Comment: Sir,  i make a script to use this libreary already, but facing a error that **createDiffieHellman** is not a function. I tried to read the [readme.md](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/diffie-hellman) but can't understand what i need to do.                      
`<script>const crypto = require('crypto');
const client = crypto.createDiffieHellman(139);
</script>`

Comment: I believe you need to `var crypto = require('diffie-hellman/browser')` somehow on your client, as this example suggests https://github.com/crypto-browserify/crypto-browserify/blob/master/test/dh.js

Comment: But you should be using https://github.com/crypto-browserify/crypto-browserify, not https://github.com/crypto-browserify/diffie-hellman. Then you don't have to require anything besides 'crypto'. Look at the /example there.

Comment: Yes, I'm using https://github.com/crypto-browserify/crypto-browserify.                                     **package.json**                                                                                                        `{
  "name": "Crypto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}`

Comment: **index.html**
`<script src="./bundle.js"></script>
<script>
 const crypto = require('crypto');
 const client = crypto.createDiffieHellman(139);
</script>
` but facing error that `createDiffieHellman` is not a function`.

Comment: Tried adding sleep after first require? Does crypto object has any other properties on it? Are there any other errors in the console? Tried attaching debugger?

Comment: Yes, `crypto` object have `createHash`, `createHmac` and other properties. I checked it with debugger.

Comment: I'd debug `browserify` internals to check if this DiffieHellman is loaded properly. Version you got seems to be from 2017. Maybe try cloning it from github (last updated 2018) instead?

Comment: Okay, but how to clone a repository and use it with node?

Answer (score 1):

See [http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/ecdh.html](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/%7Etjw/jsbn/ecdh.html) for an example of client-side ECDH key generation and key exchange in javascript.

Comment: very helpful tools to understand it.